# Transformer une unité en grandeur

Tags: expressions, constructions, substantivation

Bonjour,

j'ai observé une construction récurrente : pour désigner une quantité, certaines personnes forment un substantif à partir d'une unité de cette quantité, puis ajoutent "-age".

Par exemple, "volume" devient "litrage", "longueur" devient "métrage" ou "kilométrage", "temps" devient "minutage".

Je voudrais savoir si cette construction est correcte, et si elle est récente.

Comment: Autrement dit, la question est : A-t-on affaire à du bidouillage ?

Comment: Hahaha elle est très bonne ! Tu as un très bon rirage.

Answer (score 5):

Le suffixe [-age](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-age) existe depuis la naissance du français. C'est une évolution des suffixes latins *‑[a]ticus* et *‑aticum* qui eux-mêmes viennent du grec *‑ique*.

- *Salvaticus* → sauvage
- *Ubraticus* → ombrage
- *Formaticus* → fromage

Ce suffixe a été et est encore très productif, tous les mots cités dans la question sont utilisés. Litrage est le plus récent, Wikipédia indique qu'il est apparu au XXI<sup>e</sup> siècle.

On y retrouve le résultat d'une action ou une idée de collection :

- minuter → minutage (action de minuter: déterminer la durée précise en minutes d'une action)
- kilomètre → kilométrage (mesure du nombre de...)
- litre → litrage (idem)

On peut ajouter :

- Ampère → ampérage
- Volt → voltage (anglicisme pour tension)
- Watt → wattage
- gramme → grammage (mesure de la qualité d'un papier, g/m²)

Plus rare :

- Stérage (stère)

L'anglais semble avoir *hectarage*...

Comment: As-tu un avis sur cette construction ? Je la trouve un peu idiote, en fait, puisqu'il y a une infinité d'unités pour chaque grandeur, et donc une infinité de renommages possibles d'une grandeur : la longueur est le kilométrage, le métrage, le décimétrage, le nanométrage, etc.

Comment: Les idiotismes ne sont pas nécessairement idiots :-) Je ne vois que les sept que j'ai citées. Il ne doit pas y en avoir beaucoup d'autres. Je serais sinon surpris de lire *décibélage*, *hertzage*, *coulombage* ou "ohmage* ;-)

Comment: Il y a tonnage (pour un bateau ou une flotte de bateaux) qui est souvent utilisé, voire privilégié.